# Can I detect that a particular permission has been removed for my android app?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-4.3-jelly-bean

So with the arrival of Android 4.3 comes the ability to selectively [disable particular permissions for apps](http://techcrunch.com/2013/07/26/android-app-ops/).

This could obviously cause problems where an app loses a permission it needs to operate correctly.

Does the system broadcast a message when a permission is revoked, or how could I tell that my app no longer has a certain permission? Ideally I would like to inform the user that turning off permission A will break xyz in the application.

Comment: It's been hidden for this reason, until they come up with a mechanism for developers to adjust for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no broadcast, but you can check permissions yourself on startup(or resume, etc). [`Context#checkCallingOrSelfPermission()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkCallingOrSelfPermission%28java.lang.String%29) is provided for this.

If you want to check all your permissions, you could do something like this:

```
public static boolean[] getPermissionsGranted(Context context, String[] permissions){
    boolean[] permissionsGranted = new boolean[permissions.length];
    for(int i=0;i<permissions.length;i++){
        int check = context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permissions[i]);
        permissionsGranted[i] = (check == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
    return permissionsGranted;
}
```

Where the input Strings are the permissions' names, such as `"android.permission.INTERNET"`.